# Databinding is not working after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

I have migrated my code to AndroidX. Things are working fine except databinding.

I am getting the following error

Databinding errors after migrating to AndroidX

```
"Error:Cannot resolve the package androidx.databinding"
```

As of now, I have added the following lines in the Gradle build

```
 dataBinding {
enabled = true}
```

And in gradle.properties,

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have gone through a lot of links for the same. But didn't help.

[Androidx and databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459728/androidx-and-databinding)
[AndroidX incompatible with DataBinding Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392419/androidx-incompatible-with-databinding-android)
and so on.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55646111
Regards

Comment: @Anthony I have tried this also. It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found answer to my question.

My App has 2 modules and I used Data binding in both.  After migrating to AndroidX, one of the modules had not been converted to AndroidX (Data Binding import statements only). So this was my issue.

Solution: There are Two gradle.properties files if we see properly.

1. Project Structure -> gradle.properties
2. Android Structure -> Gradle Scripts - > gradle.properties

I migrated from Android to AndrodX through Refactor--> Migrate to AndroidX. Then following two lines have been added to 2nd gradle.properties(Android Structure -> Gradle Scripts - > gradle.properties).

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

So the other module was not converted to AndroidX (Only Data Binding). Then the same 2 lines i have added in 1st gradle.properties (Project Structure -> gradle.properties).

Then my project could build successfully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try add android.databinding.enableV2=true in the gradle properties file
Androidx and databinding are compatibles